# Spatial queries to find co-occurrences of POIs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, select-by-location, spatial-query

Given a POI database containing different types of points, e.g. `hospital` and `pharmacy`, how can I select the locations where a hospital and a pharmacy are closer than a certain threshold (e.g. `1000m`)?
The query in natural language would be expressed as:

```
select points where at least a hospital occurs within 1000m from at least a pharmacy
```

I know that I can select all hospitals and pharmacies, and compute the distance matrix between them, but I was wondering if there is a specific spatial query/operator for this kind of queries.
Ideally, I would like to express such queries in ArcGIS.

Comment: so do you have a 3rd set of points, or are you only looking for the hospitals that have a pharmacy within that distance?

Comment: I think this question could benefit greatly from the inclusion of a diagram to illustrate something that is much harder to describe using only words.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to express this in an SQL-style query within ArcGIS.

Aside from the distance matrix, a brute-force approach would be to loop through each pharmacy, perform a select-by-location for hospitals within the search tolerance, and add a flag to the pharmacy and/or hospital(s) if any hospitals are found.